# TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ubuntu, npm

After copied my Angular project from my local computer to my Linux server, I tried to run the project using `ng serve` and it didn't work. Instead it opened a new file in an editor in the console.

Then I researched and came up with `npm start`. However, that also not working.  Gives me the following error.

```
Cannot read property 'config' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null
    at Class.run (/var/www/html/node1/social2/client/node_modules/angular-cli/tasks/serve.js:22:61)
    at /var/www/html/node1/social2/client/node_modules/angular-cli/commands/serve.run.js:22:22
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@0.0.0 start: `start http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:4200 & ng serve -port 4200`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-01-23T18_49_07_743Z-debug.log
```

And I have the `.angular-cli.json` file also there. It's not missing.

What could be the reason for this ? And any solution.?

Comment: Did you tried `npm install` to install all dependencies?

Comment: Yes, I did. Still the same result

Comment: Could you please try to install angular-cli on your server?

npm install -g @angular/cli

Answer (score 0):

You may have to install angular cli on your linux server if you want to run it this way.

```
npm install @angular/cli -g
```

However, you may want to build your project for production if you want to serve it. Build it locally and push the built 'dist' folder to your server:

```
npm run ng build -prod
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

npm install -g @angular/cli