# Serving Angular App is unreachable on the browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I created a simple angular app and it's now serving on my Linux server by `npm start` (Development mode)

The problem here is that it is unreachable through the browser. The 4200 port is open too.

The app works perfect on the local computer through the address `http://localhost:4200`.

Now I tried to access the app on the server through `http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:4200`

[image]

This is the console output when the `npm start` command run.

```
> client@0.0.0 start /var/www/html/node1/social2/client
> ng serve

Unable to find "@angular/cli" in devDependencies.

The package "angular-cli" has been deprecated and renamed to "@angular/cli".

Please take the following steps to avoid issues:
"npm uninstall --save angular-cli"

** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
Date: 2018-01-23T19:40:09.118Z
Hash: 0698820565e2563b7f26
Time: 16593ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 5.79 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 178 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 550 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 33.8 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 9.15 MB [initial] [rendered]

webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

What could be the reason for this ?

Comment: If you're trying to hide your IP, you might want to update that screenshot.

Comment: You need to listen on 0.0.0.0 for it to be reachable externally.

Comment: In the package.json update `start` to `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3765

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48408943/typeerror-cannot-read-property-config-of-null)

Comment: You've asked the same exact question twice, yourself. What are you doing

Comment: Also, you colored in your IP in the address bar but it still says your IP address in the google chrome error. 'IPADDRESS refused to connect'

Answer (score 1):

The hostname and port you provided are not reachable . from outside of your Linux machine.

*ng serve* default value is targeting localhost.

Please change it to :

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: I dont think this is best practises. You may want to set there the IP address you really plan to use

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy the dist folder created after you do ng build --prod localy, and then access the app via index.html

Answer (score 0):

if your using a linux server check your ip address using `ifconfig` if your using windows run `ipconfig`
copy your ip address then run

```
ng s --host <ip address>
```